# what is "key" parameter to the Google Map widget flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm using a new version of `google_maps_flutter (0.5.0)` and in the change log, they specified "Add a key parameter to the GoogleMap widget."
 and i dont know what is this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Key](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Widget/key.html) is the property which controls how one widget replaces another widget in the tree.

Check this article to know more about keys. https://medium.com/flutter-io/keys-what-are-they-good-for-13cb51742e7d